# Explicitly set value of column to NULL when there is a default set on the Column in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table defined like:

```py
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"

    my_field = Column(Text, nullable=True, default=lambda c: "default")
```

(In my actual implementation the default function is more complicated, but I thought it pertinent to say I'm using a function to generate the default value.)

I would like to be able to explicitly set the value of `my_field` to `NULL` in some cases. I have tried:

```py
thing = Thing(my_field=None)
```

But upon the `Session.add(thing); Session.commit()` the default value is generated by the function and writes over my explicit `None`. Is there a way to use the default in general but occasionally explicitly set Null for the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a quirk in the SQLAlchemy ORM. Even if you explicitly set the value to `None` on a column with a default, it is treated as if no value was set. You need to use the `null` SQL construct in order to work around this issue. See [Forcing NULL on a column with a default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/persistence_techniques.html#forcing-null-on-a-column-with-a-default) for more detail.

```
from sqlalchemy import null

thing = Thing(my_field=null())
```